# Removing underscores that separate SNP alleles (i.e. A_T to AT) in R

Tags: r

I have SNP data with the alleles separated by an underscore (_). I am wanting to analyse them using R-package SNPassoc and it can only anlayse SNP data represented as two alleles without any separation.

I am looking for a R-script that can edit out the underscore that separates the SNPs so that I can analyse them in SNPassoc.

Regards
Mmoledi

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried?

Comment: Look at `?gsub`: `gsub("_", "", "A_T")`

Answer (score 2):

`gsub("_", "", YourStringHere)` on each string will remove underscores. See the built in help `?gsub`

Comment: Likely the alleles always have a single "_", always at the second character position, like "A_T". Likely there are many of these; for 10m `gsub` takes 28s, `sub("_", "", x)`, appropriate because there is only one occurrence to match, takes 21s and `sub("_", "", x, fixed=TRUE)`, appropriate because we are not matching a pattern but a fixed character, takes 5s. Another variant (in-place) is `substring(x, 2, 2) <- ""`, which takes 9s.